# Node snapshot causing layout issue

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Using JavaFX 9.0.4 I'm embedding some 3rd party Swing content in a JavaFX app. The 3rd party content already has its own preferred size, so I'm wrapping it with a StackPane.

However, when node.snapshot() is called this causes the SwingNode to jump back to its preferred size, manually resizing the window causes it to fill the window again.

I've also identified this only occurs if the scene is first shown without content and that content is added later.

Is this a bug? How can I work around it?

The following example recreates the issue

```
public class NodeSnapshotFunny extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
        Button button = new Button("Test");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            WritableImage image = button.snapshot(null, null);
        });
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(swingNode);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        stackPane.getChildren().add(button);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
            jPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
            jPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
            swingNode.setContent(jPanel);
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've raised this as a bug and it has been accepted. See [JDK-8198677](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8198677). Apparently this is a regression introduced in 8u40.